# Get form checkbox values and pass them through pagination?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I need to get values from some selected checkboxes and pass those values through pagination in php/mysql.  If on another page user selects other checkboxes, I need to add their values to array selected earlier.

I need this for a product comparison page.  In short I need to:

- get the checkbox values
- store them
- include the checkbox values from other pages in pagination
- and when user selects "compare" send that array to compare page.

Anybody know how to do this? Related examples would be appreciated?

Comment: the example page is not in wnglish but you can understand the problem..

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to maintain state across pages, including cookies, session variables, hidden inputs, passing them in the querystring, persisting to database, etc. In this case I would probably use a session variable.

For more info on PHP session see [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Yes i know that. But i know how to get values from checkboxwith js or ajax in my case. But problem is how to save that array i get to the session var and add other values from pagination. All done by the one page.

Comment: And here is a link to my site and how the links are formated:

http://www.forinexgroup.com/pretragaPrikaz.php?offerType=1&offerState=2&offerRegion=0&offerDest=61&offerService=3&offerMinCat=8&offerMaxCat=8&offerFromTheSea=0&offerNights=0&offerTransport=1&offerPrice=0&offerNumAdults=0&date1=28-06-2009&date2=31-07-2009

and link with pagination can be seen on the bottom of the page:

Follow the link and see..

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to load all of the pages at once in their own `div`s inside of a form.  When you click on a new page link, hide all `div`s except the one you need to show.  That way all checkboxes are submitted in the same form, making it easier to handle server-side.  That of course depends on how heavy each individual page is and how many pages there are.

Another solution would be to keep a session variable, tracking what was clicked.  Each time someone clicks to go to another page.  POST to the server a list of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using javascript to store the checkbox selection in a cookie. Here's some sample code to get you going in the right direction.

```
var aa_checkbox;

function init_checkbox(){
  //setup blank cb cookie
  if(!Cookie.read('cb')){
    Cookie.write('cb', JSON.encode({}));
  }

  //setup "associative array" to match what is currently in the cookie
  aa_checkbox = JSON.decode(Cookie.read('cb'));


  //set up each checkbox with class="remember_cb"
  $$('input.remember_cb').each(function(el){

    //mark checked if it is in the cookie
    if(aa_checkbox[el.name]){
      el.checked = 'checked'
    }

    //setup onclick event to put checkbox status in the 
    el.addEvent('click', function(){
      if(el.checked){
        aa_checkbox[el.name] = 1;
      }else{
        delete(aa_checkbox[el.name]);
      }   
    })
  })

  //save aa_checkbox back into cookie upon leaving a page
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){Cookie.write('cb', JSON.encode(aa_checkbox));};

  setup_form();

  return true;
}

function setup_form(){
  //set up form so that it adds the inputs upon submit.
  $$('form.remember_cb_form').each(function(form){
    form.addEvent('submit', function(ev){
      //clean up previously inserted inputs
      var aa_hidden_insert = $$('input.hidden_insert');
      $each(aa_hidden_insert, function(el){ 
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
      })

      var el_form = this;

      //insert hidden elements representing the values stored in aa_checkbox
      $each(aa_checkbox, function(i_value, s_name){
        if(i_value){ 
          var el_input = document.createElement('input');
          el_input.type = 'hidden';
          el_input.value = i_value;
          el_input.name = s_name;
          el_input.setAttribute('class', 'hidden_insert');
          el_form.appendChild(el_input);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

window.addEvent('domready', init_checkbox);
```

There is a [working demo here](http://jamesfunk.com/test/checkbox_cookie1.html) and a more thorough explanation [here](http://jamesfunk.com/wordpress/?p=65)

Answer (score -1):

Your pagination links could actually perform a form POST, then read the checkbox[] in ur php script, and update a hidden form element or add the value to a session, anything stateful. so your anchor could look something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.myform.submit()">next</a>
```

Comment: -1 for using JavaScript dependent form submission methods which degrade to a link to the top of the page when a perfectly good input type="submit" exists (and can be styled)

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. Its perfectly acceptable to use javascript to perform a form submission. Since a submit button cannot be styled to look like a link.. unless im missing something..

Comment: Yes but that button should be clicked only when user selects all the checkboxes he want to show in comparison view.

Comment: exactly, which is why using javascript to post the selection to the server makes complete sense.. and therefore did not deserve a -1!!!